# Deconstructing a GADT: Where am I losing the context?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have this type and these functions:

```
data Tag a where
    Tag :: (Show a, Eq a, Ord a, Storable a, Binary a) => a -> BL.ByteString -> Tag a

getVal :: Tag a -> a
getVal (Tag v _) = v

isBigger :: Tag a -> Tag a -> Bool
a `isBigger` b = (getVal a) > (getVal b)
```

The code doesn't typecheck:

```
No instance for (Ord a)
  arising from a use of `>'
In the expression: (getVal a) > (getVal b)
In an equation for `isBigger':
    a isBigger b = (getVal a) > (getVal b)
```

But I can't understand why not. `Tag a` has the context `(Show a, Eq a, Ord a, Storable a, Binary a)`, and `getVa`l ought to preserve this context. Am I doing it wrong, or is this a limitation of the GADTs extension?

This works:

```
isBigger :: Tag a -> Tag a -> Bool
(Tag a _) `isBigger` (Tag b _) = a > b
```

Edit: I changed the example to a minimal example

Edit: Ok, why doesn't *this* typecheck?

```
isBigger :: Tag a -> Tag a -> Bool
isBigger ta tb =
    let (Tag a _) = ta
        (Tag b _) = tb
    in
        a > b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your type signature for `getVal` isn't correct, you'd like the type

```
 getVal (Storable a, Ord a, ...) => Tag a -> a
 getVal (Tag v _) = v
```

The reason this isn't inferred is because you can do things like

```
 doh :: Tag a
 doh = undefined
```

Now that `a` doesn't have any constraints on it. We can do something like

```
 getVal (doh :: Tag (IO Int)) == getVal (doh :: Tag (IO Int))
```

if `getVal` had those constraints.

The only nonbottom instances of `Tag` have your typeclass constraints on them, but this isn't enough for the typechecker since then it'd be inconsistent with bottom.

---

To answer the new question

When you deconstruct types like this

```
 foo tag = let (Tag a _) = tag
               (Tag b _) = tag
           in a > b
```

GHC doesn't unify them properly. I suspect this is because the typechecker has already decided on the type of `a` by the time the pattern match is reached, but with a top level match it will unify properly.

```
 foo (Tag a _) (Tag b _) = a > b
```

Comment: Thanks again joze. I can't say I understand why it's a problem, because doesn't bottom typecheck everywhere? But for now, it's enough to know that just nope, can't be done, for some esoteric category theory reason

Comment: It's just that it's possible to make instances of `Tag` that have an `a` that's not constrained using `undefined`. Think of `undefined` as the secret constructor for any type, even ones that can't exist without `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, yet another difficulty. Why doesn't this third version of `isBigger` typecheck? It's using pattern matching! No sneaky undefined here.

Comment: Edit: Your update seems to imply that your foo function will typecheck. But it doesn't. Neither does mine above. I agree that GHC *should* know that the a and b in this pattern-matched third way are definitely Ord, but it doesn't.

Comment: No I can type check my foo function

Comment: on the version GHC 7.6.2

Comment: Ok. My bad. foo does typecheck, but isBigger3 doesn't typecheck. The pattern match has to be done top level for it to work, apparently